# How to compare two values in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have this code where I try to load a dimension table if the date of the current day has not been loaded yet. It is not loading any record, is my comparison wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_dimDate()
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
_date date := get_fecha();
_year int = get_year();
_month int = get_month();
_day int = get_day();
BEGIN

if _date <> (SELECT MAX(date) from dimDate) then
    INSERT INTO dimfechas(date, year, month, day)
    VALUES(_date, _year, _month, _day);
end if;
END
$$;
```

Both the variable `_date` and the `select` statement are of type DATE.

Comment: try `EXTRACT(DAY FROM get_fecha() - (SELECT MAX(date) from dimDate)) <> 0` but with iut tables and data and the function you use we can't really tell what is in your dimdate table

Comment: The comparison is basically correct, the bug is probably due to a logic error.

Comment: Is the table name actually `dimDate` or `dimdate`? As it stands now  the table name `dimDate` will be down cased to `dimdate`. To preserve case you would need `"dimDate"`. Otherwise you maybe selecting from wrong table.

Comment: Another thought, does `dimDate` have any values for `date`? If not `MAX(date)` will yield `NULL`  in which case you would need to do; `if _date IS DISTINCT FROM (SELECT MAX(date) from dimDate) ...` per [Comparison Functions/Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html).

Comment: Avoid CaMeL-case names like "dimDate" in Postgres if at all possible. All that gets you is confusion. Also, your explanation leaves me uneducated as to what you are trying to do exactly. How would "not been loaded yet" translate to `MAX(date) from dimDate`?